# How to collect hardware events of ArangoDB with profiling tool

Tags: profiling, arangodb, intel-vtune

On a Ubuntu server 14.04 (4.4.0-62-generic) on Intel Xeon CPU E5-2698 v4, 
I am trying to collect hardware event counts for ArangoDB with Intel VTune. 
But if I start collecting, the server will die right away.

I think the reason is that ArangoDB is collecting hardware events internally.
So I tried to turn off the ArangoDB's statistics gathering.

```
--server.statistics value
```

But still the same.

How can I collect hardware events of ArangoDB with profiling tool?

Answer (score 0):

As you are mentioning Vtune and PMU (hardware events) I assume you are using General exploration collection or likes.
Vtune has several different collectors, and some of them (hotspots, advanced hotspots) do not use PMU. If you run those, does it still crash? Also Vtune now can open results collected by linux perf record, that uses slightly different PMU sampling method. Can you try running perf record -a -e ..(events list)... sleep 30; and see if the perf collector causes same crash? If it does not, you can rename the result file from perf.data to perf.data.perf and then import to Vtune.